# Titlepage messing up the section numbers

Tags: titles, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to edit the title page but now everytime I do the section numbers get messed up (for example the section Obectives is numbered 0.1 when normally it should be just 1). In the example below I'm even using the example on the [Wikibooks Title Creation Page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{graphicx,color}     
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}\par\vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Columbidae University \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Final year project\par}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Pigeons love doves\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape John Birdwatch\par}
    \vfill
    supervised by\par
    Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}

    \vfill

\end{titlepage}

{\scriptsize blah blah blah }

\section{Objectives}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome! It has nothing to do with your title page. It is because you are using `report` rather than `article`. Recommendation: don't load packages twice, don't load packages you don't need and don't load packages unless you know why you need them.

Comment: Oh thank you, I hadn't noticed the report problem, my mistake. The packages are reminiscents of my full document (it's a physics report...), although indeed I did repeat one of them...

Comment: You still don't need `graphics` and you probably don't want `color`. If you need colour, load `xcolor`. You already have `graphicx`. `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so you need not load the latter either. But if you have `a4paper`, you probably need `geometry`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`report` expects a document with chapters. If you don't have chapters, you probably want `article` instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}\par\vspace{1cm}
  {\scshape\LARGE Columbidae University \par}
  \vspace{1cm}
  {\scshape\Large Final year project\par}
  \vspace{1.5cm}
  {\huge\bfseries Pigeons love doves\par}
  \vspace{2cm}
  {\Large\itshape John Birdwatch\par}
  \vfill
  supervised by\par
  Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}

  \vfill

\end{titlepage}

{\scriptsize blah blah blah \par}

\section{Objectives}

\end{document}
```

[image: section in article]